# Do I need to transform unseen documents before projecting them onto model topics?

Tags: python, tf-idf, lda, gensim

So I have a general bow corpus that I have created that yields documents per the format that `gensim` requires ([see here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html).)

However those documents have a lot of words that are used extremely often.  So I wanted to use a [tfidf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) to balance that out.

So I do something like

```
tfidf_model = TfidfModel(corpus)
new_corpus = tfidf_model[corpus]
```

Now I want to train my LDA

```
lda = LdaModel(corpus=new_corpus, num_topics=16)
```

And it trains and converges fine...great.  Now I have a new unseen document that I want to project onto my lda topics.  Do I always need to project this new doc with the `tfidf_model` first?  i.e.

```
transformed_doc = tfidf_model[unseen_doc]
projections = lda[transformed_doc]
```

Or can `gensim` take the original and know to apply the `tfidf` first then project onto the `lda`.

```
projections = lda[unseen_doc]
```

The `gensim` docs are a little unclear on whether or not the model knows any other previous transformations were applied to a corpus.